# Create adminhtml url with key from frontend page magento

Tags: magento-1.9, url

I want to create a link to a module of `adminhtml` in email sent from module of `frontend` of magento. I have taken reference from link: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11450146/magento-generating-url-for-a-backend-action-with-key
but this redirects to the dashboard of admin panel every time.

Please suggest me something.
I think the problem is in the key and storecode, creating url using above method gives value of storecode and also gives wrong value of Key in url.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that because the admin key is generated based on some random value that is kept in the admin session. And you cannot access the admin session on the frontend.

Comment: If we use a static value of already generated URL Key, will it work every time?

Comment: It won't work..